# useEffect hook not running to update the local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating an e-commerce website using React, and I am setting the cart items (which the user has selected to add to his/her cart) in the `localStorage` on page load and then getting them using `localStorage.getItems()`.

But for some reason when I am trying set items to `localStorage` using the `useEffect` hook, then it's not running - I don't know why. I even tried to `console.log()`, but that is also not running.

And because of that when the function which gets the item from `localStorage` runs it returns `null`.

Here is the code - please help me out.

```
import { createContext, useContext, useReducer, useEffect } from "react";
import { reducer } from "../reducer/CartReducer";

// creating Context using context API
const CartContext = createContext();


const getLocalCartData = () => { // this function returns null because useEffect did not run and not set  any thing to the localstorage.
  let localCartData = localStorage.getItem('CartItems');
  console.log(localCartData)
  if (localCartData === []) {
    return [];
  } else {
    return JSON.parse(localCartData);
  }
}

// Defining initial State for the useReducer
const initialState = {
  cart: getLocalCartData(),
  total_item: ""
}
const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {

  // Defining useReducer, dispatch, state  
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  // Add products to cart
  const addToCart = (MainProduct, amount) => {
    dispatch({ type: "ADD_TO_CART", payload: { MainProduct, amount } });
  };

  // Add products to cart
  const removeItem = (id) => {
    dispatch({ type: "REMOVE_ITEM", payload: id });
  };

  // Decrement Product Quantity
  const setDecrement = (id) => {
    dispatch({ type: "SET_DECREMENT", payload: id })
  }

  // Increment Product Quantity
  const setIncrement = (id) => {
    dispatch({ type: "SET_INCREMENT", payload: id })
  }

  useEffect(() => { // this one useEffect is not running 
    console.log("It Should run here")
    localStorage.setItem('CartItems', JSON.stringify(state.cart));   
  }, [])

  // Creating the Provider
  return (<CartContext.Provider value={{ ...state, addToCart, removeItem, setIncrement, setDecrement }}>
    {children}
  </CartContext.Provider>);
}

// Creating use context API
const useCartContext = () => {
  return useContext(CartContext);
}

export { CartProvider, useCartContext };
```

Comment: UseEffect will only run after your component renders. The initial state is obviously set when you define it, so before the component renders.

Comment: Hmm this looks like the effect should be running to me. Can you show us the file where you're using this CartProvider component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this `if (localCartData === [])` will never be true. I think you wanted to check if there is nothing in the storage. If so, it should be `if (!localCartData)`.

Then, your `useEffect`, because it has an empty dependency array, will run only once, on the mount. You would wanna add `state` as a dependency:

```js
useEffect(() => { 
  console.log("It Should run here")
  localStorage.setItem('CartItems', JSON.stringify(state.cart));   
}, [state])
```

Comment: Thank you brother it worked when I changed ```if (localCartData === [])``` to `if (!localCartData)```, and I had given the dependency before also but it was not working, but it worked after changing the if statement condition as you tell.